# WPF: Static Resource vs Resource Dictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I'm confused what's the difference between the two. I understand you use a static resource for example like a brush or something that you define once and then you use multiple times in the xaml. But what does the Resource Dictionary do? what's the difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resource dictionary *holds* resources whereas a static resource is a *static reference to* a resource. In other words, when you use a static resource, it must already exist in a resource dictionary somewhere in scope.

Comment: so in other words, a resource dictionary contains static resources?

Comment: Well a resource dictionary contains resources. And references to those resources can be either static or dynamic. The word 'static' in static resource is describing the reference, not the resource.